# How can I show custom MailItem properties in the email header in Outlook 2007?

Tags: vba, forms, email, outlook

I work in a manufacturing environment. I am setting up some custom fields in my Outlook inbox that will allow me to quickly categorize emails by what material code(s) and lot number(s) the email is about. In my inbox, I have two new columns, "Material" and "Lot No". I wrote a macro that allows me to pull up a UserForm to quickly edit these values through the UserProperty prop on each email.

[Image of columns in Inbox to demo what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp9RG.png)

[image]

I know that I can open each email individually, go to "Design This Form" and manually add the fields into the header, but this is obviously not practical (I'm doing this whole exercise to improve my efficiency, after all). Is there a way to programmatically do this?

[Image of manually-added fields in email header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wewSf.png)

[image]

I am searching all over and striking out. I'm not even able to find a good reference for how to manipulate the form elements of a received email (or at least a reference that I understand).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MailItem.UseProperties.Add` / `MailItem.Save` to add/modify user properties.

Comment: Hi, Dmitry. Thank you for the reply. I was probably unclear in my question, so I apologize. To clarify, adding the properties to the MailItem's metadata is not a problem; where I am running into trouble is getting those

Comment: Sorry, @Dmitry. The trouble with typing on mobile is hitting "enter" too soon... What I was saying was that I am having trouble getting those fields to display in the header without manually editing each email's form. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is - if your folder view is configured to show a particular user property, all you need to do is call MailItem.UserPorperties.Add, set the value of the UserProperty.Value, then save the item (MailItem.Save). Does it not work?